# xaml Convert ID to String without using ComboBox

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I've been using code like this

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CompaniesViewModel.CompaniesCollection}"                              
    SelectedValuePath="CompanyId"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CompanyId}"
    IsEnabled="False"
    DisplayMemberPath="CompanyName"      
    />
```

To display a Company Name in a ComboBox.  Notice how the IsEnabled is set to false...that's because I really don't want the user to use the ComboBox.  I am just using it as an easy way to convert an ID to string for display purposes.

When I put items in a Grid and there are a lot of them, I think it is really hurting the rendering performance.  When I remove the ComboBox it loads in a split second.  When the ComboBox is used in the code it can take 20 seconds.

I guess my question is I think I should be using a Label or TextBlock but not sure how to get the binding to work correctly as They don't have an ItemsSource or a SelectedValuePath or SelectedValue.

I thought about writing an IValueConverter but not sure how to bind/pass in the 3 values.  I'd have to pass in the collection, the ValuePath and the Value ID.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: when you say `I am using the Grid`, do you mean some sort of DataGrid? is so, then you want to use Cell Templates (with textblock) vs. Cell Editing Templates(with combobox) and that would speed things up drastically. Update, and me or someone will help you out, otherwise, try out @HighCore 's answer..

Comment: also `ItemSource` is for controls that bind to lists. But don't forget that all controls have `DataContext`, you can bind to that! you can bind TextBox's Text as well

Answer (score 1):

Put a

```
public Company Company {get {return CompaniesCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CompanyId == CompanyId); }}
```

property in the ViewModel.

Comment: I don't have access to the CompaniesCollection in this particular model. For instance Each one of my Contacts has a CompanyId but not a reference to an actual Company without doing a lookup. I could include the company name in each one of my contacts but don't then if a company name changes I'd have to search through all of my contacts and replace the name.

Comment: +1 love one liners! @DanP, to your comment above, how is that you don't have access to CompaniesViewModel.CompaniesCollection when you bind to it in your XAML?

Answer (score 0):

I welcome any of you to examine my code to see if you can make it more efficient but this is what I ended up doing.

```
<cc:LookupLabel  
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CompaniesCollection}"                              
    SelectedValuePath="CompanyId"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CompanyId}"                                
    DisplayMemberPath="CompanyName"      
    />
```

And below is the LookupLabel derived from Label and INotifyPropertyChanged.  I'm not sure how Microsoft implements this efficiently but this was my best stab at it.  In particular the GetContent method listed at the bottom.  All the other stuff is just the messy DependencyProperty declarations.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace CustomControls
{
    public class LookupLabel : Label, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public LookupLabel()
        {
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }       

        #region ItemsSource

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(LookupLabel)
                , new UIPropertyMetadata(null, LookupLabel.ItemsSourceChanged)
                );

        private static void ItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            LookupLabel t = d as LookupLabel;            
            t.NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemsSource");
            t.Content = GetContent(t);
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get
            {
                return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
            }
        }
        #endregion ItemsSource

        #region SelectedValue

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValue", typeof(object), typeof(LookupLabel)
                , new UIPropertyMetadata(null, LookupLabel.SelectedValueChanged)
                );

        private static void SelectedValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            LookupLabel t = d as LookupLabel;
            t.NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedValue");
            t.Content = GetContent(t);
        }

        [Localizability(LocalizationCategory.NeverLocalize)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        public object SelectedValue
        {
            get
            {
                return (object)GetValue(SelectedValueProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value);
            }
        }
        #endregion SelectedValue

        #region SelectedValuePath

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValuePathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValuePath", typeof(string), typeof(LookupLabel)
                , new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, LookupLabel.SelectedValuePathChanged)
                );

        private static void SelectedValuePathChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            LookupLabel t = d as LookupLabel;
            t.NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedValuePath");
            t.Content = GetContent(t);
        }

        [Localizability(LocalizationCategory.NeverLocalize)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        public string SelectedValuePath
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(SelectedValuePathProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SelectedValuePathProperty, value);
            }
        }
        #endregion SelectedValuePath

        #region DisplayMemberPath

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberPathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMemberPath", typeof(string), typeof(LookupLabel)
                , new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, LookupLabel.DisplayMemberPathChanged)
                );

        private static void DisplayMemberPathChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            LookupLabel t = d as LookupLabel;
            t.NotifyPropertyChanged("DisplayMemberPath");
            t.Content = GetContent(t);
        }

        [Localizability(LocalizationCategory.NeverLocalize)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        public string DisplayMemberPath
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty, value);                
            }
        }
        #endregion DisplayMemberPath

        protected static object GetContent(LookupLabel label)
        {
            if (label.ItemsSource == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label.SelectedValuePath))
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label.DisplayMemberPath))
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (label.SelectedValue == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            object result = null;
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo valuePropertyInfo = null;
            foreach (var item in label.ItemsSource)
            {
                if (valuePropertyInfo == null)
                {
                    valuePropertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty(label.SelectedValuePath);
                    if (valuePropertyInfo == null)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                if (valuePropertyInfo.GetValue(item, null).Equals(label.SelectedValue))
                {
                    var displayPropertInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty(label.DisplayMemberPath);
                    if (displayPropertInfo == null)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = displayPropertInfo.GetValue(item, null);
                        break;
                    }                    
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd help if you were to paste only the relevant code, please

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your combobox is taking too long to load because your collection has a lot of items.

You shouldn't be loading all your companies if you'll just show one of them, as a general good-practice.

I don't quite grasp your intent in using the combobox. Is it the style? can it be enabled in the future?
If it is only an easy way of displaying the CompanyName then i'd suggest the following:

1. Bind directly to CompanyName property.

-OR-

1. in the code-behind, create a calculated property named "CompanyDisplayName" that gets your company name.
2. Bind to it in the XAML
3. in the code-behind, whenever the current selected Company instance or the CompanyId changes fire 'OnPropertyChanged("CompanyDisplayName")

Try a TextBlock or a readonly TextBox to enable copy/paste;

For more info on the NotifyPropertyCahnged paradigm read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)